# Backbone.Model how to listen for changes on multiple attributes only once

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-model

Say I have a `Layout` model with `width` and `height` properties. And Say I want to update a view when either of them changes, but the updating process in computational intensive and requires the value of both `width` and `height`. The computation process also updates the `ratio` property of the model.

If I do

```
this.listenTo(this.model, 'change:width change:height', this.doLayout);
```

I will end up with two `doLayout` calls in the worst case and both will do the same, wasting resources.

If I do

```
this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', function(model) {
    if(model.hasChanged('width') || model.hasChanged('height')) {
        this.doLayout();
    }
});
```

On first sight it looks like I solved the problem of doing the `doLayout` calculations twice. **But** the way `Backbone.Model` works is that since `doLayout` sets `ratio`, I will end up with a second `change` event. The `changedAttributes` for the first event is `{width: ..., height: ...}` and for the second one it's `{width: ..., height: ..., ratio: ...}`. So yeah, `doLayout` is executed twice again...

Any solution other than rewriting the `set` method?

Edit: Note that I need a general purpose solution. Hard-coding the width/height/ratio special case is not acceptable. In reality I have many more computed properties which are updated based on others and the way Backbone handles the `change` event does not work well in this situation.

Comment: When I need to control change events firing, I almost always write my own wrapper to set.

Comment: Sounds like I will do this as well. But triggering a custom change event means duplicating things like `hasChanged`, `changedAttributes` etc.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest thing to do, for me anyway, is to change the way you think about the events. For instance, in this case, it isn't that you want to only do it once, it is that you want to do something after both have finished.

The easiest way to do that here would be to debounce the event:

```
this.listenTo(this.model, 'change:width change:height', _.debounce(this.doLayout, 1));
```

That way it will only run once, even if it is called a bunch of times synchronously.

Note: The exact timing behavior of `_.debounce(..., 1)` depends on the browser's treatment of very small timeouts. If immediate synchronous-like behavior is important, you could replace the usage of `_.debounce` with a custom debouncer written using [`setImmediate`](https://github.com/YuzuJS/setImmediate).

Comment: Thanks. Introducing an artificial delay is not an option though. Using debounce feels like covering the issue with some makeup without actually solving it. In reality I have properties which are updated at 60 fps, rendering performance has absolute priority. It performs well, but could be better (in some cases I get 3 or 4 change events and thus unnecessary renderings).

Comment: If `debounce` is too slow (since it uses `setTimeout`), you could look into debouncing using `setImmediate` and its browser polyfills. That would queue the function to call at the end of the current event-loop pass, so you would not even incur an event-loop tick. In those cases, I'd be surprised if this introduced significant delays.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a great solution which shouldn't have any side effects.

```
Backbone.Mode.extend({
    set: function() {
        this.changed = {};
        Backbone.Model.prototype.set.apply(this, arguments);
    }
});
```

If you look at the Backbone source and check where `this.changed` is used it should be clear what this does. The `change:[attr]` type of events aren't affected at all. But within the `change` event both `changedAttributes()` and `hasChanged()` will only return the properties that where changed by the very last `set` call.

I consider submitting a pull-request to Backbone which makes this configurable as an option to `set`.